# onActivityResult data to inputstream chrashes on jellybean

Tags: android, camera, inputstream

This is code i'm using

```
Intent i = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            Main.this.getContentResolver().delete(data.getData(), null,
                    null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }
    } else {            
        is = null;
    }
}
```

I'm doing this way because i don't want to save pics to dcim folder.
It is working fine on samsung, htc and some other devices but it crashes on alcatel one touch 5020x Jelly Bean 4.1.1,
returns null pointer exception.

Is there another way to do this, but not to save pics to dcim folder.
I have seen many solutions to do this but all of them save a pic to dcim folder

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

> I'm doing this way because i don't want to save pics to dcim folder.

Then include `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, to tell whichever camera app handles your request where to put the image. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field.

Your code is written to not do anything of what is documented. Instead, you are assuming that the camera app will return a `Uri` of where an image is. **This is not part of the documented protocol**, and so your code will fail when interacting with many camera apps.

> Is there another way to do this, but not to save pics to dcim folder.

This code will put the image in another spot on external storage:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import java.io.File;

public class CameraContentDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private File output=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    output=new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "CameraContentDemo.jpeg");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));

    startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // use the output File object
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried You code, it works on all devices but now HTC one x saves pic to dcim. Alcatel doesn't.

Comment: @Crni03: Then there is a bug in the HTC One X camera app. There is not much that you can do about this, other than to not use third-party camera apps, and instead take pictures yourself, using `android.hardware.Camera` or `android.hardware.camera2.*`.

Comment: Thank You for Your help, i have checked out camera hardware and in some time i will develop my own camera ap, but for now You have given me an idea to how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but it works!

```
final static int cameraData = 13579;
final static int camera2Data = 97531;
InputStream is = null;
int camera2 = 0;
SharedPreferences spData;
public static String spName = "MySharedString";
```

camera start:

```
if (camera2 == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                output = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),
                        "CameraContentDemo.jpg");
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));
                startActivityForResult(i, camera2Data);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
            }
```

onActivitrForResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == cameraData) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                Main.this.getContentResolver().delete(data.getData(), null,
                        null);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                camera2 = 1;
                if (camera2 == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    output = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),
                            "CameraContentDemo.jpeg");
                    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(output));
                    startActivityForResult(i, camera2Data);
                }
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spData.edit();
                editor.putInt("cam2", 1);
                editor.commit();
            }
        } else {
            is = null;
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == camera2Data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(output);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spData.edit();
                editor.putInt("cam2", 0);
                editor.commit();
            }
        } else {
            is = null;
        }
    }
}
```

So, like i said, its not the best solution but it works.
When the app starts for the first time on Alcatel, it starts with the old code, crashes and catcher the exception, saves camera2 variable to be 1, and starts the camera again with the second code that works fine.
When i load on other devices, it works fine to and no pics are saved to DCIM folder